# Не запускается приложение из службы Windows (C#)

Tags: c#, ооп, service

Добрый день! Я написал два C# проекта: службу и консольное приложение. Смысл службы заключается в том, чтобы постоянно следить за приложением и в случае его выключения снова запускать (разрабатываю не вирус!). Исходный код запуска таков:

```
private static void launch()
{
    var p = new Process
    {
        EnableRaisingEvents = true,
        StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo
        {
            FileName = appPath
        }
    };
    p.Exited += launchAgain;
    p.Start();
}

private static void launchAgain(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    launch();
}
```

где appPath - путь консольного приложения

Проблема в том, что если написать это в консольном приложении, а не службе, то все работает. Через службу, в принципе, тоже все работает. Но проблема заключается в том, что процесс консольного приложение отображается в диспетчере задач, но не отображается сама консоль.

Пробовал баловаться с параметрами CreateNoWindow и UseShellExecute у StartInfo - безрезультатно.

Comment: А под какой учёткой запускается служба? У стандартных учётных записей для служб (LocalService/NetworkService) ограниченные права, и ограниченные возможности по взаимодействию с рабочим столом. Так что, отсутствие окна консоли не выглядит чем-то необычным, по крайней мере для проектов, работающих на Win32 API (C++, Delphi, и др. языки)

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/267838/how-can-a-windows-service-execute-a-gui-application

Comment: @velial, LocalSystem. С правами проблем нет, т.к. он пишет в EventLog

Comment: Может стоить описать более детально, что у вас не получается и что не так? Пока из вопроса я вижу, что у вас консоль не отображается в диспетчере задач.

Comment: @DenisBubnov, как раз таки консоль отображается в диспетчере задач, но нет самого UI консоли. Т.е. сам процесс запущен и висит в диспетчере, но нету окна ввода консоли

Comment: @DenisBubnov, у меня есть служба, которая вызывает отслеживает событие Exited процесса, путь которого задается в переменной `appPath`. Если это событие сработало (т.е. процесс `appPath` закрыли), служба вновь должна запустить этот же процесс(код запуска расписан выше). Служба запускает этот процесс (его видно в диспетчере задач), но сам процесс (т.е. консольное приложение), не отображается на экране (просто висит в фоне)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Служба и UI - вещи несовместимые. Конечно, в системе есть <s>костыли</s> способы которые позволяют делать службы со своим UI, но это концептуально неправильно. Выбрав вариант "служба с UI", вам придется решать проблемы "а что если пользователь вышел из системы", "а что если в системе два сеанса активно", "а что если у текущего пользователя нет прав" и т.п.

Если вам нужно взаимодействие с пользователем - значит, вашим выбором должна стать обычная программа, которую вы будете запускать одним из трех способов:

1. через планировщик заданий;
2. через ключ реестра HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run;
3. через папку "автозагрузка".

Чтобы сделать программу у которой не будет своего интерфейса, можно проступить так:

1. создать новый консольный проект, после чего в свойствах переключить тип проекта на "оконное приложение";
2. создать новый проект winforms, после чего удалить из него единственную форму (также имеет смысл удалить ссылку на сборку System.Windows.Forms);
3. также вы можете переделать вашу службу в обычное приложение без UI удалив из проекта компонент-наследник ServiceBase и стерев все лишнее в Main (также не будет лишним удалить ссылку на сборку System.ServiceProcess).